# term derivation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbols

I am trying to take partial derivative of sum:
$$Cv_m=\sum_{i=1}^{Ns}Cv_i \frac{\rho_i}{\rho_m},$$ where $Cv_i$ are constants.
I want to take derivative 
$$\partial{Cv_m}/\partial\rho_i=Cv_i /\rho_m$$

```
D[Sum[Subscript[Cv, i]*Subscript[rhoY, i]/rhom, {i, 1, 
    Ns}], Subscript[rhoY, i]]
```

I expected $Cv_i/\rho_m$, but it gives me $\sum_{i=1}^{Ns}Cv_i/\rho_m$

How get rid of sum symbol?

Comment: Try avoiding subscripts for a start, see if it simplifies things at all.

Comment: I chose it because Wolfram "considers" that it is an argument and it gives me 0. For example:
Dt[rhoY[i]/rhom] gives me $-\frac{\text{rhoY}(i) Dt[\text{rhom}]}{\text{rhom}^2}$ instead $\frac{Dt[\text{rhoY[i]}]}{rhom}-\frac{\text{rhoY}(i) Dt[\text{rhom}]}{\text{rhom}^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look, the output of the following contains a `KroneckerDelta`:

```
a = D[Sum[Cv[i]*ρ[i]/ρ[m], {i, 1, Ns}], ρ[j]]
```

> $$\sum _{i=1}^{\text{Ns}} \frac{\text{Cv}(i) \delta _{i,j}}{\rho (m)}$$

so the result is correct.

You can get rid of the sum with

```
Assuming[j \[Element] Integers && 1 <= j <= Ns, Simplify[a]]
```

> $$\frac{\text{Cv}(j)}{\rho (m)}$$

Comment: Thank you, Henrik! 

But this piece of code gives me 0: 
        D[Sum[Cv[i]*\[Rho][i]/\[Rho][m], {i, 1, Ns}], \[Rho][j]] .
No KroneckerDelta

Comment: But if replace index j by i. it gives me the same sum but without $\rho[i]$

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of Mathematica? I am running version 11.3 and it works. Unfortunately, I don't have a quick fix.

Comment: The version of Wolfram is 10.4.

Comment: I'm on 10.0.2.0 and get the same problem as the OP. This is a bug right??

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Well, I am not sure. The result by version 10 is clearly incorrect. But I am not sure wether the developers meant to cover this situation in that release. But... well... yeah, I guess it is a bug.

Comment: even for Wolfram 11.0.0 it gives 0

Comment: Indexed differentiation was added in versions 11.1